# Cloud function for sending notification not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a notification to "PLAYER 2" when a new game is added.
Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNewGameNotification= functions.database.ref('/GAMES/{gameId}/PLAYER 2').onWrite(event => {
const player2uid = event.params.val;

const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/USERS/${player2uid}/fcm`).once('value');

return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise]).then(results => {

const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
// Notification details.
const payload = {
  'data': { 
        'title': "Tienes una nueva partida"
  }
};

// Listing all tokens, error here below.
const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

// Send notifications to all tokens.
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
  // For each message check if there was an error.
  const tokensToRemove = [];
  response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
    const error = result.error;
    if (error) {
      console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
      // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
      if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
          error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
        tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
      }
    }
  });
  return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
});
});
});
```

When it is executed, in the firebase console says

```
 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Like if it were null but the fcm is there, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think instead of this:

```
const player2uid = event.params.val;
```

you want this:

```
const player2uid = event.data.val();
```

**Edit:**

This update to your code contains some added checks and a simplification.  This works for me.

The database structure for storing the token (or tokens) is critical.  The tokens are the keys, not the values.  The values are not significant and can be simple placeholders, such as booleans.

For example:

```
  "USERS" : {
    "Roberto" : {
      "fcm" : {
        "eBUDkvnsvtA:APA...rKe4T8n" : true
      }
    },
    "Juan" : {
      "fcm" : {
        "fTY4wvnsvtA:APA91bGZMtLY6R...09yTLHdP-OqaxMA" : true
      }
    }
  }
```

.

```
exports.sendNewGameNotification= functions.database.ref('/GAMES/{gameId}/PLAYER 2').onWrite(event => {
const player2uid = event.data.val();

return admin.database().ref(`/USERS/${player2uid}`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
   if (!snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log('Player not found:', player2uid);
        return;
    }
    const tokensSnapshot = snapshot.child('fcm');
    if (!tokensSnapshot.exists()) {
        console.log('No tokens for player: ', player2uid);
        return;
    }

    // Notification details.
    const payload = {
      'data': {
            'title': "Tienes una nueva partida"
      }
    };

    // Listing all tokens, error here below.
    const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    // Send notifications to all tokens.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
      // For each message check if there was an error.
      const tokensToRemove = [];
      response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
          console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
          // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
          if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
              error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
              tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
          }
        }
      });
      return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
});
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, that is solved but now it throws me  Error: Invalid registration token provided. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with FCM any idea why?

Comment: Are you storing one token under `/USERS/${player2uid}/fcm` or multiple?

Comment: I am storing just one

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: Oh man, thank you for pointing out that the tokens had to be put in the database as keys!  You saved me hours of banging my head against the wall.